# Is there an out-of-the-box solution for PWM controlling?

Tags: wifi, sonoff

I need to ventilate a room because of my Resin printers. I have a discarded kitchen extractor hood with an EBM fan in it. It takes 10v PWM to control the speed. And the lights have a driver. 
To control the lights I can use a cheap Sonoff wifi switch. But does anyone know if there is a wifi pwm controller for the fan? 
Searching google you get the standard LED 'pwm' controllers, but those don't output a pwm signal.

I've connected an arduino to the fan and was able to control it. Of course not at full speed because the PWM signal is only 5v. (MOSFET would make 10v pwm possible).

But before I embark on a DIY solution, I was hoping someone knows if there is a Sonoff like solution that outputs PWM.

Comment: what exact fan do you have? ... the fan might be using an open collector PWM input, which means that 5 V signal should work and the reason for not attaining ful speed is not what you think

Comment: It's an EBM D3G146 HQ14-34. The diagram says 10v PWM. But my question is: is there an out-of-the-box solution for this. Before I start with an arduino/rpi diy route

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly make a wifi controlled PWM fan with an arduino and a wifi module. It would be fairly easy to throw together and would probably be a fun and rewarding project. All though if you don't want to do it yourself, I would recommend looking up DC motor controllers. Those are all PWM and are fairly inexpensive. You can get one with the voltage you want plus a remote. See the following listing ->
[https://www.amazon.com/uniquegoods-Controller-Digital-Display-Regulator/dp/B07BPYBRL5/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=motor%2Bspeed%2Bcontroller%2Bwith%2Bremote%2B10v&qid=1590835468&s=hi&sr=1-3&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BPYBRL5)